# Use Javascript to get url and redirected url requests

Tags: javascript, get-request

I want to use javascript to get all the urls I travel to in a browser. For example,  if I go to a url, I want to get that url, the page it redirects me to, and any intermediary redirects.  Is there a get request I can use in javascript that can grab just those urls (or another one that might get more but would be a superset of what I want)?

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location

Comment: Asik- I'm unsure on how to use that to get what I need.  If a page is redirected using javascript through multiple urls, I can't see how document.location would give me anything but the final url.

Comment: document.location gives current URL and you can not get requested url (previous url) using javascript

Comment: I've been able to get some of the previous urls using javascript by saving the pages request histories, but this also loads a lot of extra stuff (any request the page had made).  I was asking if there was a cleaner (and more reliable) way of doing it